# Error on XML serializing on a non-serializable object on a non-serialized method

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm using this code

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

To serialize an object.

Now I get an error on this line of code (which is in an object nested way down in the to be serialized object)

```
public override List<BrokenRule> GetBrokenRules() {
```

the error is
Csla.Validation.BrokenRule cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Now that is correct, but I thought `methods` were not serialized, so what is the problem (the `Csla.Validation.BrokenRule` is not used elsewhere)

If it is by design, this behavior, is there a way to runtime say "ignore this part of the object"?

Editing the objects code with attributes etc. is not allowed....

Comment: Are you sure it's this method causes problem? Perhaps you have a property of `BrokenRule` type somewhere (to example, `SelectedItem`)?

Comment: In a baseclass, only another method which uses the `BrokenRule` type

Comment: Exception should contain row at which it occurs (if you have pdb-file). Point is ***Methods**, indexers, private fields, and read-only properties **are not serialized*** (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163161.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, because it made me look again, and tadaa: I found a property which is a Collection of `BrokenRule` :-( So that brings me to the second part of my question: is there a way to runtime say "ignore this part of the object"?. I know I can add `XmlAttributes` on the property, but it's a baseclass way up in the hierarchy and I'm not allowed to edit...

Comment: Then your question become [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1089967/1997232). You can try to create  `ShouldSerializePropertyName` methods (which return `false`) in inherited class (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e.aspx)), I am not sure if it will work for base property.

Comment: @Sinatr - ShouldSerializePropertyName() doesn't seem to work, perhaps because it isn't guaranteed to return false always.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could serialize this class to XML is to create an [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfaxz1a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the derived class and pass `XmlAttributeOverrides` that specify that the property which returns a class is `XmlIgnore`.  However, as specified in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you *must* cache and re-use this `XmlSerializer`:

> To increase performance, the XML serialization infrastructure dynamically generates assemblies to serialize and deserialize specified types. The infrastructure finds and reuses those assemblies. This behavior occurs only when using the following constructors:
>
> XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type)
>
> XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type, String)
>
> If you use any of the other constructors, multiple versions of the same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a memory leak and poor performance. The easiest solution is to use one of the previously mentioned two constructors. Otherwise, you must cache the assemblies in a Hashtable, as shown in the following example.

Rather than a `HashTable`, in simple cases I will construct my `XmlSerializer` in the static constructor for the class I need to serialize.  This is fairly lazy, and is guaranteed to be thread safe.  Thus, for instance:

```
public class NoParameterlessConstructor
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public NoParameterlessConstructor(string value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public NoParameterlessConstructor NoParameterlessConstructor { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    static XmlSerializer serializer = null;

    static DerivedClass()
    {
        var xOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        var attrs = new XmlAttributes() { XmlIgnore = true };
        xOver.Add(typeof(BaseClass), "NoParameterlessConstructor", attrs); // Must use BaseClass here not DerivedClass!

        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DerivedClass), xOver);
    }

    public static XmlSerializer DerivedClassXmlSerializer { get { return serializer; } }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And then, to test:

```
public static class TestNoParameterlessConstructor
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var derived = new DerivedClass { Id = 1, NoParameterlessConstructor = new NoParameterlessConstructor("Test") };
        var xml = XmlSerializationHelper.GetXml(derived, DerivedClass.DerivedClassXmlSerializer);
        Debug.WriteLine(xml);
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DerivedClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Id>1</Id>
</DerivedClass>
```