# Class properties ignored by XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have a class representing a book and when I run the `SerializeToXmlElement()` method, it includes the class but not the class properties. How can I ensure that the public properties are included in the XML output?

**Book class**

```
[XmlType("Edition")]
public class Book 
{
    #region Attributes
    private string series;
    private string title;
    private string isbn;
    private string pubDate;
    #endregion Attributes

    #region Encapsulated fields
    [XmlElement]
    public string Series { get => series; set => series = value; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string Title { get => title; set => title = value; }
    [XmlElement("ISBN")]
    public string Isbn { get => isbn; set => isbn = value; }
    [XmlElement("Publication_Date")]
    public string EditionPubDate { get => pubDate; set => pubDate = value; }
    #endregion Encapsulated fields

    #region Constructors
    public Book() { }
    #endregion Constructors

    #region Methods
    public XmlElement SerializeToXmlElement()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
            new XmlSerializer(this.GetType()).Serialize(writer, this);
        }
        return doc.DocumentElement;
    }
    #endregion Methods
}
```

**Input**

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","utf-8",null));
XmlNode rootnode = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Root_Node"));
XmlNode editionsNode = rootnode.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Editions"));

Book b = new Book();
b.Isbn = "978-0-553-10953-5";
b.Title = "A Brief History of Time";
XmlNode edition = doc.ImportNode(b.SerializeToXmlElement(), false);
editionsNode.AppendChild(edition);
edition.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Impressions"));
```

**Output**

```
<Root_Node>
    <Editions>
        <Edition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <Impressions />
        </Edition>
    </Editions>
</Root_Node>
```

Bonus points for someone who can tell me how I can remove the `xmlns:xsi` and `xmlns:xsd` attributes from the Edition node in the XML output.

Comment: Thanks, that was an accident on my part. It's declared as `public` in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `true` for the second parameter to [`XmlDocument.ImportNode(XmlNode, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode.aspx):

> *deep*
>   
>  Type: System.Boolean
>   
>  **true** to perform a deep clone; otherwise, **false**.

This indicates that the child nodes of the incoming node should be copied as well.  Thus, your code should look like:

```
XmlNode edition = doc.ImportNode(b.SerializeToXmlElement(), true);
```

*Bonus points for someone who can tell me how I can remove the `xmlns:xsi` and `xmlns:xsd` attributes from the Edition node in the XML output.*

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/935749/3744182) to *[Omitting all xsi and xsd namespaces when serializing an object in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/625927/3744182)* by [Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98713/thomas-levesque) you need to pass an `XmlSerializerNamespaces` with an empty name/namespace pair into [`Serialize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z5zfc6h.aspx):

```
public XmlElement SerializeToXmlElement()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
        new XmlSerializer(this.GetType()).Serialize(writer, this, ns);
    }
    return doc.DocumentElement;
}
```

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tYjIRe).

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Is there also a way to omit inherited properties from being serialized to XML?

Comment: @ryansin - there are already questions about this, e.g. [XMLSerialize and EXCLUDE the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26916696/3744182) and [.net XmlSerializer, ignore base class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1089967/3744182).  If those don't meed your needs I'd suggest asking another question.

Comment: Thanks @dbc I was able to include ShouldSerializeXXX methods to override base class properties